# Kotlin learning: Is there a more functional way to initialize this 2D array (Chess board) from a FEN String?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, functional-programming

looking to expand my Kotlin skill a bit here by asking if there's a more functional way to achieve the working code I have below.

To briefly describe what's going on:

1. A `FENString` is wrapper around a `String` that `require()` it be the correct format (8x8 etc.)
2. We declare our 2D array and initialize all to null
3. Init func iterates through characters in the FENString doing the appropriate response, either moving the rank/file pointers along or getting a `Piece.fromFEN` and putting it in the current position

```kotlin
typealias BoardState = Array<Array<Piece?>>

class Board(fen: FENString) {
    val state: BoardState = Array(8) { Array(8) { null } }

    init {
        var rank = 0
        var file = 0
        fen.value.forEach {
            if (it.isDigit()) {
                file += it.digitToInt()
            } else if (it.isLetter()) {
                state[rank][file] = Piece.fromFEN[it]
                file += 1
            } else if (it == '/') {
                rank += 1
                file = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to replace the null initialization with code that does the same thing as the code in the snippet?

For completeness my definition of FENString included below:

```kotlin
data class FENString(val value: String) {
    companion object {
        val INITIAL_BOARD_FEN = FENString("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR")
    }

    init {
        val ranks = value.split('/')
        require(ranks.size == 8) { "FEN ($value) rank length ${ranks.size} not legal." }
        for (file in ranks) {
            var length = 0
            for (char in file) {
                if (char.isDigit()) {
                    length += char.digitToInt()
                } else if (char.isLetter()) {
                    length += 1
                }
            }
            require(length == 8) { "FEN file length $length not legal." }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Heres the definition of Piece for even more completeness as we call Piece.fromFEN:

```kotlin
data class Piece(val type: PieceType, val color: Color, val char: Char) {

    enum class Color {
        WHITE, BLACK
    }

    enum class PieceType {
        ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, KING, QUEEN, PAWN
    }

    companion object {
        val fromFEN: Map<Char, Piece> = hashMapOf(
            'P' to Piece(PieceType.PAWN, Color.WHITE, 'P'),
            'N' to Piece(PieceType.KNIGHT, Color.WHITE, 'N'),
            'B' to Piece(PieceType.BISHOP, Color.WHITE, 'B'),
            'R' to Piece(PieceType.ROOK, Color.WHITE, 'R'),
            'Q' to Piece(PieceType.QUEEN, Color.WHITE, 'Q'),
            'K' to Piece(PieceType.KING, Color.WHITE, 'K'),
            'p' to Piece(PieceType.PAWN, Color.BLACK, 'p'),
            'n' to Piece(PieceType.KNIGHT, Color.BLACK, 'n'),
            'b' to Piece(PieceType.BISHOP, Color.BLACK, 'b'),
            'r' to Piece(PieceType.ROOK, Color.BLACK, 'r'),
            'q' to Piece(PieceType.QUEEN, Color.BLACK, 'q'),
            'k' to Piece(PieceType.KING, Color.BLACK, 'k'),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I would say it’s likely that a functional solution would be super complicated and messy if it’s even possible. Aside from the 2D structure, you have elements (digits) that count as more than one space. I suppose you could take it one step closer to being functional by splitting the string by the slashes first and then iterating the ranks, but what you already have is concise and elegant, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about things at the wrong level.  Ignore functional/procedural-  your first job should be to stop working on a string of mixed data, and work on individual pieces of data.  Split the string into an array of strings by splitting on the '/' char.  Then you can process each individual location as a location.  And at that point you can assume its always a number followed by a letter and throw an exception if the data is bad.  That will greatly simplify your code, and fix a variety of bugs I can see in it.

Comment: Also-  your format is a bit weird.  It doesn't specify whether a piece is white or black, so it isn't actually usable.  It doesn't really seem to do anything well-  it's not a minimal representation of a board, and it's not a particularly easy to parse format.  Since the amount of data is small, why not just have 1 object per square with both the color and type?  Or an array of pieces with the type, color and chess notation location (a1, e4, etc)?  Either of those would be easier to parse, barely any larger, and easier to understand.

Comment: It's hard to understand your points without an example. Also these are just snippets of the code that's important, there's other code for moving pieces this is just the initialization which is what I'm asking about. As to whether it's useable: the project is fully playable right now I am working on calculating legal moves and getting a GUI together, so I don't find that feedback too helpful.

Comment: @BillyUdders If you're just trying to set up the starting position, it's completely pointless.  The starting position is static, just set up the board rather than initializing it from a string.  You're just making life harder on your self, replace it with a dozen or so direct sets.  If you're using it to serialize multiple possible positions (say to save a board, or set up a game in progress) then it's not sufficient because it doesn't differentiate black and white pieces.  Either way it's a poor idea.

Comment: Basically it looks like you read a technique on how to save from a programming book in the 80s where they tried to save every byte they could.  It's not a technique you'd use in modern day.

Comment: @GabeSechan FEN is a real format for chess data. It's concise and easy to write. This class looks like it was written to import chess boards that were written in this notation, not just the starting setup for a chess game. I don't think it would be practical to ask users of this app to type out their board descriptions in JSON.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I never said anything about JSON.  But an 8x8 matrix would make much better sense.  Or a list of pieces and their rank/file.  This is a horrible format.  And it used only to set up the default state of the board is a direct quote from the OP.  Also at this point you're missing contexts, responses by him were deleted by either him or the mods.

Comment: This is not a SaaS product, maybe storing state in MongoDB would be your next suggestion :)

Comment: My next suggestion would be fixing your attitude.  When you treat people like this, there's no wonder nobody else is willing to help you.

Comment: I've had quite helpful and useful commentary from others! Have a great day, Gabe. Chessprogramming.com is an illuminating website, might be some interesting reading for you.